# WinJS.UI.DatePicker in Universal App

Tags: datepicker, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1

Apparently `WinJS.UI.DatePicker` since WP 8.1 is no longer supported in WP os, while it is in W8.1
Honestly, to me, this makes no sense at all, but in VS the debugger simply rejects the arguments, so it's pretty clear I can't use it.
Since I was trying to develop a Universal app, how can I make a Universal DatePicker, without building it programmatically myself?

I can't believe Win ecosystem does not provide anything like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the current time the DatePicker control is not supported on Windows Phone 8.1 for WinJS applications, see this documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn632432.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Yes I had seen that, but unfortunately they do not tell what method they have implemented instead... (if they do have one)